# How to put Mac to sleep programmatically with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sleep

I am writing a program to make my MacBook Pro go to sleep when the app opens but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't know if this is something to do with power management or something but from what I found on is that it has something to do with IOKit.pwr_mgt. Your help would be appreciated! The code below is just how to enable sleep mode but not put the computer into sleep mode. I also found the applicationDidFinishLaunching function so the code is in that function.

```
var assertionID: IOPMAssertionID = 0
var success = IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to power management. You will actually need to run a script with your app.

The easiest way to accomplish this is first disable your App sandbox capability.

Next go to your app `info.plist` and add `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` key and a description, something like `"This app needs your permission to put the display to sleep."`.

Now you just need to execute an Apple script telling application system events to sleep. `"tell application \"System Events\" to sleep"`:

Create a method to execute that script:

```
func startScreenSleep() {
    let script = "tell application \"System Events\" to sleep"
    guard let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: script) else { return }
    var error: NSDictionary?
    appleScript.executeAndReturnError(&error)
    if let error = error {
        print(error[NSAppleScript.errorAppName] as! String)
        print(error[NSAppleScript.errorBriefMessage] as! String)
        print(error[NSAppleScript.errorMessage] as! String)
        print(error[NSAppleScript.errorNumber] as! NSNumber)
        print(error[NSAppleScript.errorRange] as! NSRange)
    }
}
```

---

And call it from your ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startScreenSleep()
}
```

Comment: It says for me that System Events isn't running

Comment: Did you check your system preferences > security & privacy > privacy tab > Automation > Your App > System Events check box? When you run your app for the first time it should prompt you to to allow it if your App sandbox is disabled and if the NSAppleEventsUsageDescription is in your info plist

Comment: You might need to allow your system to run apps from anywhere. Go to your Applications > Utilities > Terminal and run `sudo spctl --master-disable`

Comment: @TheCodeGuy https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3n4by04ub0kvol/put%20screen%20to%20sleep.zip?dl=1

Comment: It is not really prompting me to allow if the app sandbox is disabled

Comment: You should see this dialog when running the app linked above https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cs2u8wnf4s4sqv/dialog%20box.png?dl=1 After clicking ok it should sleep. I have just tested it in a different machine running Mojave. Just needed to lower the OS target

Answer (score 1):

Just run bash script "pmset sleepnow"

```
    @IBAction func sleepAction(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try safeShell("pmset sleepnow")
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
    
    @discardableResult 
    func safeShell(_ command: String) throws -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()
        
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash")
        task.standardInput = nil

        try task.run()
        
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        
        return output
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static func enterSleep() {
    let port = IOPMFindPowerManagement(mach_port_t(MACH_PORT_NULL))
    IOPMSleepSystem(port)
    IOServiceClose(port)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**